# A value of type 'String?' can't be returned because function has return type of 'Future<String>?'

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, future

[The documentation](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) says:

> If the function has a declared return type,  then update the type to
> be `Future<T>`, where `T` is the type of the value that the function
> returns.

When I do that with this code, I get an error: *A value of type '`String?`' can't be returned from the method 'amethod' because it has a return type of `Future < String>?`.*

Why is it giving that error and what is the correct way to return a non-void value from an `async` function? Thanks.

```
class Demo{
  
 Future<String>? amethod() async{
 String? variable1;
   
   //await ...
   
  return variable1;    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your function wants to return `variable1`, which is of type `String?`.  Since the function is asynchronous, its return type must be `Future<String?>`, not `Future<String>?`.  The two are *not* the same:

- A return type of `Future<String>?` means that the function returns either `null` or a `Future`.  That `Future` completes to a non-nullable `String`.  This is almost never what you want as a return type.
- A return type of `Future<String?>` means that the function always returns a `Future`, never `null`.  That `Future` completes to either `null` or a `String`.

Comment: Very clear and precise explanation. This is the type of answers we should hope for.

Answer (score 3):

You need change `Future<String>?` to `Future<String?>?` or `Future<String?>`